# asp.net panel control visibility issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a code which checks unique ID availability status.. if ID is available it should make panel visible otherwise the panel visibility is hidden. But it is not working. If i set panel visibility to false in page load it works.. but panel visibility code inside text change event of textbox, doesnt work. In my view page script manager is present to update content inside update panel. What am i doing wrong.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="PnlUsrDetails" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <table>
       <tr>
           Enter unique no: <asp:TextBox ID="txtUniqueNo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="txtUniqueNo_TextChanged"/>      
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <div id="checkusername" runat="server"  Visible="false">
              <asp:Image ID="imgstatus" runat="server" Width="17px" Height="17px"/>
              <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
           </div>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
          <div>Panel content</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

server side code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false; 
        PopulateCategory();
        getSubCategories(CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        //CategoryDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
    }
}

protected void txtUniqueNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUniqueNo.Text))
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(DB.DatabaseConnString());
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from gallery where unique_no='" + txtUniqueNo.Text + "'", conn);

        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            checkusername.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/images/unavailable.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Unique Id Already Taken";

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                checkusername.Visible = true;
                Panel1.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/images/tick.png";
                lblStatus.Text = "Unique Id  Available";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string mess = ex.Message;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        checkusername.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

My file upload is also in update panel,, which loses its file on upload. Suggest me any alternative approaches to achieve this functionality... 
Thanks

Comment: are you pressing enter after entering the ID in textbox??

Comment: Are you sure that  `Panel1.Visible = false;` is called? Also, it seems that you are setting `checkusername.Visible = true;` in both `if` branches which seems to be wrong.

Comment: Check if you are using viewstate (viewstate=true). Are you using scriptmanager or updatepanels?. Check too if the postback run after change the textbox.

Comment: yes i have checked it in debugging,, that line is getting executed successfully.. i am not pressing enter on textbox. on lost focus it updates label.

Comment: Can you post your onLoad Event? perhaps some code is showing it each postback.

Comment: @Phx  updated question with page load,, thanks

Comment: You can write  if (!IsPostBack), no need to write this.page.IsPostBack. (advice)

Comment: ok ,, but same problem with panel visibility.

Comment: write <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">. Delete the first Visible=false on IsPostBack and try it.

Comment: @phx i did it,, panel was not visible at first.. but i was not able to make it visible programmatically,, i did Panel1.visible=true

Comment: @Phx  why is it not happening inside textchange event of textbox.. on pageload it works fine. any ideas..

Comment: Cuase textbox allways exist  and Panel1 not exist (visible=false).

Answer (score 2):

Problably cause the Control is not rendered (visible=false) and no viewstate is saved before.
Try to hide and show it with styles:

First:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Panel1.Visible = false; Comment
            PopulateCategory();
            getSubCategories(CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue);
            //CategoryDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
        }
    }


protected void txtUniqueNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUniqueNo.Text))
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(DB.DatabaseConnString());
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from gallery where unique_no='" + txtUniqueNo.Text + "'", conn);

        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            checkusername.Visible = true;
           Panel1.Style.Add("display", "none");
            imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/images/unavailable.png";
            lblStatus.Text = "Unique Id Already Taken";

        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                checkusername.Visible = true;
                Panel1.Style.Add("display", "block");
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/images/tick.png";
                lblStatus.Text = "Unique Id  Available";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string mess = ex.Message;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        checkusername.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it did not work,, shall i post entire code in my question.

Comment: Delete the first Panel1.visible=false. Delete too the attribute Visible="False".

Comment: Here is the update,,, if i put panel inside asp:update panel,.. then it works,,, but i have a server side file upload control,, which loses file if i put it in update panel... :( Thanks u so much

Comment: I asked you before if you are using update panel with script manager. It's very important for this question. Put the file upload out the update panel and refresh only the update panel ( UpdatePanel1.Update();). Anyway, check my edited answer, it have to works too.

Comment: sorry was confused. lots of comments. My functionality is of showing panel when ID is available. so file upload is basically hidden with panel. I cannot put it outside panel becoz its aligned with form. suggest me any other alternatives if u have,. Thanks

Comment: Put the panel1 into another UpdatePanel and  update it when you change the visibility. Using Partial-Page Rendering will help you to achieve it.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.ASPX

Answer (score 0):

File upload control will not work inside Update panel in this case it will lose selected file for sure.Since you have asked for alternative approach.One way is to check unique no availablity using jquery. Here is the perfect working link [Check-UserName-Availability-jquery](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-UserName-Availability-in-ASP.Net-using-JQuery.aspx) to check username availability. use this example to check unique no.
Ajax has success and error methods, so you can place your form inside a div with unique id and toggle its visibility on ajax result.
Upoo the success of ajax you can show your div in which form is present. This will eliminate the need to use script manager and update panel.